# Restar los valores de 2 inputs en un ciclo for javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo un ciclo for que repite varias veces 3 inputs uno que es del valor de un objeto otro input para los adeudos y el ultimo input para mostrar el resultado el problema es que solo me toma en cuenta la primera iteración del ciclo. a continuación el código

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php for ($i=0; $i <3; $i++) { ?>
  <label>fila <?php echo $i; ?></label>
  <input type="number"  id="precio" >
<input type="text" class="aduedo">
<input type="text"  id="resultado" value="0" disabled>
    <br>
  <?php }  ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.aduedo').keyup(function () {
        var valor_inicial=document.getElementById('precio').value;
        var valor = parseInt(valor_inicial);
        var valor_restar = 0;
        $('.aduedo').each(function () {
          if ($(this).val() > 0) {
            valor_restar += parseInt($(this).val());
          }
        });
            
        $('#resultado').val(valor - valor_restar);
              
    });
});
</script>
```

[image: vista grafica]

mi idea es que en la fila 0 en el primer input se ponga un valor y en el input del medio se ponga otro valor y en el input de la izquierda te devuelva el resultado de la resta de ambos valores
y en la fila 1 se haga igual pero se pueda trabajar con distintos valores. muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Cada fila es una operacion independiente?

Comment: en HTML los elementos no deben tener el mismo id, este debe ser único. Estás creando 3 elementos con id=precio y 3 con id=resultado.

Comment: @David081 si cada fila es una operacion independiente

Comment: @Pipe si lo se pero como estan en un ciclo for pues se trepite el idy les podria poner un id por ejemplo  id="precio<?php echo $i; ?>" pero no se como pasar esa variable a la funcion de javascrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LA técnica es la siguiente: Envuelves cada fila en un elemento padre (puede ser un div). Luego usas el evento oninput para detectar cualquier cambio en el input, es evento es mejor que el onkeyup o el onkeypress, porque te detectará incluso si se copia y pega.

Luego a la función del evento se ingresa como argumento "this", es decir se pasa a sí mismo, esto es muy útil para determinar "cuál es el input que ha detonado el evento" (ya que todos los inputs apuntan a la misma función).

Ya con esto, preguntas por el padre del (this) que sería el div en el ejemplo de abajo. Y desde el padre comienzas a buscar los valores de sus respectivos hijos.

```js
function update(campo)
{
   //buscamos al padre, el div
  let padre = $(campo).parent();
  
  let precio = $(padre).find(".precio").val();
  let adeudo = $(padre).find(".aduedo").val();
  $(padre).find(".resultado").val(Number(precio)-Number(adeudo));
}
```

```css
div{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 40px 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>fila 1</label>
  <input type="number" oninput="update(this)" class="precio" >
  <input type="number" oninput="update(this)" class="aduedo">
  <input type="number" oninput="update(this)" class="resultado" value="0" disabled>
</div>

<div>
  <label>fila 2</label>
  <input type="number" oninput="update(this)" class="precio" >
  <input type="number" oninput="update(this)" class="aduedo">
  <input type="number" oninput="update(this)" class="resultado" value="0" disabled>
</div>

<div>
  <label>fila 3</label>
  <input type="number" oninput="update(this)" class="precio" >
  <input type="number" oninput="update(this)" class="aduedo">
  <input type="number" oninput="update(this)" class="resultado" value="0" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, disculpa y tu método sirve cuando el número de inputs es dinámico ? Es decir en mi programa real los inputs pueden ser igual al número de registros que hay en una base de datos...

Comment: @EMMAHUERTA Sirve para la cantidad de filas que sea. Recuerda que si la respuesta te ha ayudado puedes marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!!

Comment: muchas gracias la verdad no lo he podido implementar...pero espero funcione lo que me genera duda es si sirve estando en un ciclo foreach por que en mi proyecto real tengo registros que tienen un valor y un adeudo y bueno los campos serian dependiendo e numeor de registros en la bd... muchas gracias de todos modos saludos

Comment: @EMMAHUERTA Si, sirve para aplicarlo en iteraciones for/foreach. Lo único es que el primero calculo debes hacerlo del lado del servidor. Es decir los valores de los 3 inputs deben llegar cargados al cliente (incluyendo el input de resultado). Luego el javascript se encarga de realizar los cálculos posteriores cuando el usuario edite algún campo